# Directory tree listing under Windows/TotalCommander

Tags: windows, directory-listing, tree-view

Under Linux, and on some ftp servers, there is this culture of using `*.lslR` files. These are the text output of `ls -lR`, which lists the content of a directory tree. [In Midnight Commander](http://midnight-commander.org/wiki/doc/virtualFS/extfsModules), you could actually browse these files as if they were actual filesystems. This way you can browse the directory content of FTP servers, your backups on CDs, etc. It is an awesome feature which I used heavily.

Is there a similar solution for Windows and, preferably, Total Commander? Create a listing of filesystem into text file and then opening it and browsing it like it is an actual filesystem?

Comment: Not that this helps you.. but I just use the regular midnight commander under windows using WSL.  Using WSL, for *most* things.. I no longer need to find windows equivalents.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas wow, I didn't know that WSL exists! And it's done by Microsoft omg... I am astonished! Thanks!